# PHP Interface type hinting error

Tags: php

Code:

```
interface TestInterface
{
    public function foo(String $key);
}
class Test implements TestInterface
{
    public function foo(String $key)
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Test::foo() must be compatible 
>       with TestInterface::foo(String $key, Test\String key) in index.php

Comment: Are those in the same file? Seems like a namespace issue.

Comment: 1. the error message doesn't match your posted code (two params). 2. why use `String` (class) instead of `string` (basic type)? 3. apart from that, I agree with ishegg. most likely a namespace issue

Comment: @Jakumi `String === string`

Comment: then I'm an idiot. have used namespaces but never encountered a problem where namespace\String was expected.

Comment: Hm you're right though, you can't name a class `String` (PHP 7+), so I don't really get the error. There seems to be a constant in the error too which is even weirder... OP we need to you give more information. Don't bail after asking a question!

Comment: @OP what version of php are you using? [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) for `string` came in php 7.0.0

Comment: @WeeZel There is no error in PHP 7, but I get an error in version 5.6.4

Comment: @WeeZel I think he has a lower version than 7 because a) he named it `String` with an S so maybe he *does* have a class named that (not possible after PHP7+) and b) the error points to some kind of namespace `Test\String`... weird!

Comment: yeah, in php < 7 you apparently can define String with and without a namespace oO ah ... the quirks of php never cease to amaze me

Comment: Problem namespace :( 
using \ string instead of string

Comment: if you want to get rid of the error in 5.6.4 you need to remove the type hinting - it simply just doesn't work! it'll still work in 7+... once all your code is running on 7 you can add the type hinting back. **NOTE:** the same goes for `bool`, `float` & `int`

Comment: This time also gives an error in php 7 OMG :/

Comment: no type hinting tested on https://eval.in/860318 (php 5.6.23 & 7.0.8). if your're just using 7+ then my advice would be to change `String` to `string`

Comment: @WeeZel thanks :) I decided not to use any kind of imposition. I am using PHP 7, but the version of my customers is unfortunately sometimes downgraded.